# Lwt.async() not working as expected

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, ocaml, ocaml-lwt, mirage

I'm developing a web service in `Ocaml` on top of MirageOS(Unix) and at the moment I'm having some trouble with `Lwt.async()`. The Lwt documentation states the following:

> `val async : (unit -> 'a t) -> unit`
>
> async f starts a thread without
>   waiting for the result. If it fails (now or later), the exception is
>   given to Lwt.​async_exception_hook.
>
> You should use this function if you want to start a thread that might
>   fail and don't care what its return value is, nor when it terminates
>   (for instance, because it is looping).

So I immediately considered Lwt.async as a good candidate to run some tests and check that actually the execution is asynchronous. Unfortunately it's not working as expected. My code is the following:

```
let http_callback conn_id req _body =
  Lwt.return(Uri.path (Cohttp.Request.uri req))
  >>= function
     | "/tester" -> Cohttp_lwt_body.to_string _body >>= fun res -> 
        log_lwt ~inject:(fun f -> f "Testing") >>= fun () ->
        Lwt.async(fun () -> TEST.start 100 res !listOfIP);
        H.respond_string ~status:`OK ~body:("DONE") ()
  in
     let spec = H.make ~callback:http_callback () in
     CON.listen conduit (`TCP 8080) (H.listen spec)
```

For the sake of clarity, TEST.start executes a series of threaded operations. I assume that it doesn't really matter what the function inside Lwt.async is doing, considering that whatever returns/does should be ignored. Am I wrong?

In the end, my question is: why actually the client has to wait for the thread to receive the OK response? With or without async the behaviour is basically the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control will only switch back to the HTTP handler if the async thread blocks waiting for something. If it just uses the CPU 100% until it's done then the async thread will probably run to completion first. Try putting a sleep in the tests to check.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will give it a try asap.

Comment: I've substituted completely the piece of code called by TEST.start with Lwt.return(Unix.sleep 10) but the result is exactly the same. When I run curl -X POST --data something http://10.0.0.2:8080/tester the console hangs and I have to wait for 10 seconds to get the reply. I mean if I call sleep from a secondary thread I really don't expect the main thread to stop..

Comment: Lwt threads are not preemptive. They are actually promises. Try using `Lwt_unix.sleep 10.` instead of `Lwt.return (Unix.sleep 10)`.

Comment: Thanks, it works now! Now I need to figure out if there is a way of fixing this without a `sleep`.

Comment: You have passed a function to `async` that is resolving an Lwt promise (wrongly called *thread* by Lwt). This function is running, together with the rest of your Lwt promise resolvers, in a single system thread, in a single OCaml process. So, you need to avoid calling anything blocking from `Unix.` or other modules anywhere in your program, and use the Lwt replacements for everything. Those use system worker threads in the background (if needed) to resolve the various Lwt promises in your main system thread. You probably already saw [`Lwt_unix`](http://ocsigen.org/lwt/dev/api/Lwt_unix).